# exeuting command in background

Tags: python, shell

Trying to execute shell command in background using pythons commands module

```
>>>import commands
>>>output = commands.getstatusoutput("find / > tmp.txt &")
   sh: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with the syntax ? How should it be executed then ?

Tazim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [getstatusoutput documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput), `commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)` is executed as

```
{ cmd  ; } 2>&1
```

so your command is run as if it was

```
{ find / > tmp.txt & ; } 2 >& 1
```

and the `;` is not valid after the `&` in such a command.

You should use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family) to simulate the old-style `os.spawn` commands.

Try

```
subprocess.Popen("find / > tmp.txt", shell=True)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the subprocess module. I'd remove the rest of the flibbify-flabiddy (or at least make a note) because it's strictly *nix specific. There are ways to use the subprocess module to process stdin stdout stderr in python in a cross platform manner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to directly execute a command in background like that. Particularly, it's because commands module does not run the command through bash, which is what usually parses the ampersand.

You should do a fork/exec call from the os module to run things in background.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a [daemon](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) to run your process in background.